# Как заменить фигуры изображениями в Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas

Здравствуйте. Есть пример создания игры типа match3 http://rembound.com/articles/how-to-make-a-match3-game-with-html5-canvas. В примере элементы в виде фигур залитые цветом. Как заменить фигуры картинками. В javascipt и canvas не силен.

Answer (score 1):

Там же есть ответ как загружать и рисовать картинки:
http://rembound.com/articles/how-to-load-and-draw-images-with-html5-canvas